# re.compile regex assistance (python, beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Using this code from a different thread

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<script type="text/javascript">
    window._propertyData = 
    { *** a lot of random code and other data ***
    "property": {"street": "21st Street", "apartment": "2101", "available": false}
    *** more data ***
    }
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")
pattern = re.compile(r'\"street\":\s*\"(.*?)\"', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
print pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
```

This gets me the desired result:

> 21st Street

However, i was trying to get the whole thing by trying different variations of the regex and couldn't achieve the output to be:

> {"street": "21st Street", "apartment": "2101", "available": false}

I have tried the following:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\"property\":\s*\"(.*?)\{\"', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

Its not producing the desired result.
Your help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: typo here it's `property` not `propety` and [try this](https://regex101.com/r/DBAiBF/1)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo, and trying out your link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per commented above , correct your typo and you use this

```
 r"property\W+({.*?})"
```

[**RegexDemo**](https://regex101.com/r/DBAiBF/3)

`property :` look for exact string

`\W+` : matches any non-word character

`({.*?})` : capture group one

- `.*`  matches any character inside braces `{}`
- `?`   matches as few times as possible

Comment: @MikeS. i am glad that i could  help , happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
\"property\":\s*(\{.*?\})
```

capture group 1 contains yor desired data

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/DOre86/8)

Sample Code:

```
import re

regex = r"\"property\":\s*(\{.*?\})"

test_str = ("window._propertyData = \n"
    "    { *** a lot of random code and other data ***\n"
    "    \"property\": {\"street\": \"21st Street\", \"apartment\": \"2101\", \"available\": false}\n"
    "    *** more data ***\n"
    "    }")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
   print(match.group(1))
```

[Run it here](https://repl.it/En2H)

Comment: Thanks, it worked well, but the next answer regex was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It may be long but work's fine

```
\"property\"\:\s*(\{((?:\"\w+\"\:\s*\"?[\w\s]+\"?\,?\s?)+?)\})
```

https://regex101.com/r/7KzzRV/3

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import ast
data = """
<script type="text/javascript">
    window._propertyData =
    { *** a lot of random code and other data ***
    "property": {"street": "21st Street", "apartment": "2101", "available": false}
    *** more data ***
    }
</script>
"""
property = re.search(r'"property": ({.+?})', data)
str_form = property.group(1)
print('str_form: ' + str_form)
dict_form = ast.literal_eval(str_form.replace('false', 'False'))
print('dict_form: ', dict_form)
```

out:

```
str_form: {"street": "21st Street", "apartment": "2101", "available": false}
dict_form:  {'available': False, 'street': '21st Street', 'apartment': '2101'}
```